# IWD One Step Checkout to work with EE Reward points

Tags: magento, reward

I have been trying to customize IWD One step check latest CE version to work with EE reward points or store credit during check out as an additional payment method but so far no luck..scratching my head for weeks..will appreciate if anybody can help me..

I have tried different methods but the options doesnt show out in checkout page.

Few examples i did:
base/default/layout/onepagecheckout.xml

added these blocks

```
<block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.payment.additional" as="additional" />
<block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.payment.methods_additional" as="methods_additional" />
```

and this

```
<block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.payment.methods.scripts" as="scripts" />
<block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.payment.methods.additional" as="additional" />
```

Also in template/onepagecheckout/onepage/payment.phtml; i tried to add these codes:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('methods_additional', '', true, true) ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('additional') ?>
```

Also in template/onepagecheckout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

Tried adding:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('additional') ?>
```

Comment: This line comes in the layout XML file: <block type="enterprise_customerbalance/checkout_onepage_payment_additional" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/payment/store-credit-additional.phtml" name="customerbalance" /> Does that PHTML file exist in your template directory?